# Enabling mix precision in tensor flow model training decreases the speed instead of increasing it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using **NVIDIA RTX-2060** (with turing cores) for deep learning model training. As mentioned on online forums enabling mix precision training helps turing architecture cards train faster than without mix precision training. When i enabled mix precision training, the per step time increased instead of getting decreased. I can't fathom why this is happening, i'd really appreciate anyone suggesting a solution. I've spent so much money buying this gpu, it's no use if i can't get it to train models faster.

Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,3)),
        keras.layers.Dense(3000, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    
    model.compile(optimizer= 'SDG',
                 loss= 'categorical_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

%%timeit -n1 -r1 # time required toexecute this cell once

model = create_model()
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_categorical, epochs=50)
```

**Things You Must Know:**

> I have installed cuda and cudnn successfuly and tensorflow can detect my gpu.

> I have installed tensorflow-gpu.

> I am training my model on ciphar10 data set with nvidia rtx 2060 gpu.

Jupyter Notebook i've been using to benchmark: [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/satishgunjal/image-classification-ann-cpu-gpu-benchmarking)

Comment: How're you benchmarking?

Comment: Using tensor flow output time for each epoch

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking with the pre-trained model?

Answer (score 4):

As you're using the **CIFAR** dataset, I think your last layer activation should be `softmax` instead of `sigmoid`, and also your loss function `categorical_crossentropy`. And make sure it is `float32`.

```
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', dtype=tf.float32)
```

---

You should set a **mixed-precision** global policy at the beginning, right after `tf` import. Here are some tips when using mixed precision on GPUs. From [Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision).

### Increasing your batch size

If it doesn't affect model quality, try running with double the `batch size` when using `mixed precision`. As `float16` tensors use half the memory, this often allows you to double your `batch size` without running **out of memory**. Increasing `batch size` typically increases training throughput, i.e. the training elements per second your model can run on.

### Ensuring GPU Tensor Cores are used

Modern NVIDIA GPUs use a special hardware unit called **Tensor Cores** that can multiply `float16` matrices very quickly. However, **Tensor Cores** require certain dimensions of tensors to be a multiple of **8**.

In the examples below, an argument is bold if and only if it needs to be a multiple of 8 for Tensor Cores to be used.

```
- tf.keras.layers.Dense(**units=64**)
- tf.keras.layers.Conv2d(**filters=48**, kernel_size=7, stride=3)
- tf.keras.layers.LSTM(**units=64**)
- tf.keras.Model.fit(epochs=2, **batch_size=128**)
```

---

If you follow properly this procedure, then you should get the leverage of using `mixed-precision`.  [Here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/mixed-precision-training/index.html#tensorflow) is one good reading from NVIDIA.

Comment: Do you mean that using mixed precision alone won't increase the speed, rather it would leave out around half the space so that we can double the batch size and get more computations done in the same amount of time ?

Comment: I tried your solution, but the performance is still the same. Increasing batch size decreases accuracy so it's not gonna help. My problem is still there, i can't make it run faster with mix precision.

Comment: Can you give some reproducible code fully (not the shallow one)?

Comment: I've added the link to original notebook in my question

Comment: The link to the other notebook is not asked. And if you're following this notebook, then, please re-run the program by following the official instruction that I mentioned in my answer and update your query with a new result. In the notebook, there's plenty of issues there.

Comment: I've already re-run the code with your instructions. Without altering the batch size nothing improves. If we double the batch size with multiples of 32, speed increases but that also leads to higher loss.

Comment: If possible, please update with (1), model definition (2). hyper-parameter (3). training logs.. and if possible please provide reproducible code. Otherwise, it's hard to break down.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official guide from [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision), To use mixed precision properly, your `sigmoid` activation at the end of the model should be `float32`. Because we set the policy `mixed_float16`, the activation's `compute_dtype` is `float16`. Thus, we have to overwrite the policy for this layer to `float32`.

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        keras.layers.Dense(3000, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        # keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'), # NOTE: Replaced this line by two lines below
        keras.layers.Dense(10,),
        keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', dtype='float32'),
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

**Put everything together, we have the complete source code for training CIFAR10 dataset with mixed precision:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        keras.layers.Dense(3000, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        # keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'),
        keras.layers.Dense(10,),
        keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', dtype='float32'),
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# There are 10 image classes
classes = ["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

X_train_scaled = X_train / 255
X_test_scaled = X_test / 255

y_train_categorical = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes= 10, dtype='float')
y_test_categorical = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes= 10, dtype='float')

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    model = create_model()
    model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_categorical, epochs=50)

model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test_categorical)
```

With my GPU `NVIDIA RTX2080`, I have compared the performance between with (called `P1`) and without (called `P2`) using mixed precision and found that:

1. **Training time**: Because the time per step was rounded and they are the same for `P1` and `P2` (~6ms), I compared the overall training time for 50 epochs of `P1` which is significantly faster than `P2` (464s vs 501s).
2. **Testing time**: `P1` is still faster than `P2` (3ms/step vs 4ms/step)
3. **Test performance (acc)**: `P1` is better than `P2` (~55.61% vs ~50.77%)